How would I add an "extended" tabstop in snippets?
I'm trying to make a snippet with multiple choices and I need only one of the choices to have a subset of choices after selecting it.
For Example:
"Basic Furniture": {
    "prefix": "!bfurniture",
    "description": "Basic Furniture Template",
    "scope": "json",
    "body": [
        "{",
        "  \"id\": $1,",
        "  \"props\": [",
        "    \"${2|nothing,chair,all|}\"",
        "  ],",
        "  \"description\": [",
        "    \"${0:...}\"",
        "  ]",
        "}"
    ]
}

Here I want it so that if I choose nothing then it will continue on to the next tabstop (e.g. $0}, but if I choose chair then it would open another choice like ${3|wooden,plastic|} and only then continue on to the next tabstop ($0).
Any ideas on how I can pull this off?
I tried using the nested tabstops like the documentation showed but their functionality is different.
I also tried nesting another choice tabstop inside the $2 choice tabstop but only resulted in $2 turning to plain text while $3 would become the only choice tabstop.
(e.g. ${2|nothing,chair ${3|wooden,plastic|},all|})

When you select the nothing choice you want no output?  Not even nothing?  And choosing chair wouldn't output chair but would open another choice?

If you don't find an answer you like you could do it a silly way like this:

Make the main snippet only do half of the snippet you have now, up to the choices.

Then create different snippets based on all the choices you have.


For example create a separate 'chair' snippet with the prefix chairbf.
Now when you choose 'chair' in the main snippet you can type 'bf' after to get the completion for the chair choice snippet. This separate snippet will have the chair submenu options plus the ending of the main snippet you have now.
You'll have to create the other choice snippets, for 'nothing' and 'all', as well.
Edit:
For the string completion problem you can:

Move both quotes to the chair snippet so there is no string when doing the second snippet completion


Edit2 Above way works. This way will leave an errant quote

If you don't want to do that you can also force completions in strings by using the keyboard shortcut control+space


Hi!
Thanks for the help, this certainly is going on the right track, though I noticed  another issue with this while testing it out.
While this IS a viable option for normal values, choice snippets don't work inside strings unless I were to change my snippet settings. So if I were to choose chair and then write something afterwards it wont pop up the snippet menu.
Preferably, I would like to keep user settings untouched via the extension.

Updated my answer which gives you two choices

You can structure your snippet to include all potential options, and then manually navigate to and edit the relevant parts after insertion.
for ex:
{
  "Basic Furniture": {
    "prefix": "!bfurniture",
    "description": "Basic Furniture Template",
    "scope": "json",
    "body": [
      "{",
      "  \"id\": $1,",
      "  \"props\": [",
      "    \"${2|nothing,chair,all|}${2/(chair)/$3: ${4|wooden,plastic|}/}\"",
      "  ],",
      "  \"description\": \"${0:...}\"",
      "}"
    ]
  }
}


Hope this helps.

Hey, thanks for the answer.
While this does do the job, I would prefer not to have extra unnecessary tabstops for users because of the annoyance of how annoying and inefficient tabbing continuously is. What if there were multiple choices with subchoices? Clogging up the line with a bunch of subchoices for each choice would be very inefficient and time consuming.
Do you think there might be an easier solution for this case?

You can create placeholders that act as conditional sub choices by setting a default value that users can overwrite, but it won't require tabbing if they leave it as is.
in modified code, 1: if you select nothing or all it skips $3 and $4. @: if you select chair it shows choice between wooden and plastic at $4 allowing you to pick one of those options.
